# Why have I errors while reading and writing from firebase in reactjs?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

When I use the below code I get the events in my console from firebase.

```
getEvents = () => this.db.ref('events');

this.props.firebase.getEvents().on('value', snapshot => {
            console.log(snapshot.val());
        });
```

When I add the below line of codes it gives this error for both of the following functions:
TypeError: this.db.ref(...).where is not a function

GetEvents function is showing the events on the calendar. updateEquipments function creates new equipments

```
GetEvents = uid => {
                this.db.ref('events').where('ownerId', '==', uid).get();
            };

UpdateEquipments = id => {
            this.db.collection('equipments').doc(id);
        };
```

[image]

```
this.props.firebase.GetEvents(this.props.uid).then(querySnapshot => {
                querySnapshot.forEach(doc => {
                    newEvents.push(doc.data());
                    this.setState({
                        events: newEvents,
                    });
                });
            });


 createEquipment = ({ title, desc }) => {
        const { equipments } = this.state;
        const newEquipmentId = uuidV4();
        const updatedEquipment = {
            ...this.state.modal,
            id: newEquipmentId,
            ownerId: this.props.uid,
            title,
            desc,
        };
        const nextEquipments = [...equipments];
        nextEquipments.push(updatedEquipment);
        this.props.firebase
            .UpdateEquipments(newEquipmentId)
            .set(updatedEquipment)
            .then(
                this.setState({
                    equipments: nextEquipments,
                })
            )
            .catch(error => {
                console.error('Create New Equipment error', error);
            });
    };



    render() {
        if (this.state.events) {
            return (
                            <div className={'col-2'}>
                            Equipments:
                            <FloatingActionButton
                                mini={true}
                                className={'m-2'}
                                onClick={() => this.handleEquipments()}
                            >
                                <ContentAdd />
                            </FloatingActionButton>
                            <Sidebar
                                events={this.state.equipments}
                                onClickEvent={this.handleEquipments}
                            />
                        </div>
                        <div style={{ height: 500 }} className={'col-8'}>
                            <DragAndDropCalendar
                                events={this.state.events}                          
                                backend={false}
                            />
                            <Dialog
                                title="Task"
                                modal={false}
                                open={this.state.modalOpen}
                            >
                                <Modal
                                    event={this.state.modal}
                                    onRequestClose={this.handleClose}
                                />
                            </Dialog>
                            <Dialog
                                title="Equipments"
                                modal={false}
                                open={this.state.equipmentsOpen}
                                onRequestClose={this.handleClose}
                            >
                                <Modal
                                    event={this.state.modal}
                                    onRequestClose={this.handleClose}
                                    onCreatEvent={this.createEquipment}
                                />
                            </Dialog>                            
                        </div>
            );
        }
    }
```

Here is the full code : https://github.com/Tim1023/react-scheduler-firebase

Answer (score 0):

Firebase contains two databases:

- The original Realtime Database, which stores data as a single JSON tree.
- The newer Cloud Firestore, which stores data in collections and documents.

Both databases are part of Firebase, but they're completely separate and you can't use the API for one of them on the other.

And that's precisely what you're doing here:

```
this.db.ref('events').where('ownerId', '==', uid).get();
```

The `this.db.ref('events')` seems to be for the Realtime Database, but then `.where('ownerId', '==', uid).get()` is code that only works on Cloud Firestore.

The solution is to stick to the [API](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database) and [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/start) for the Realtime Database, which you seem to be actually using.